# How to fetch id from bottom-up approach in django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How to fetch id of `Process` and `Client` model in `Emp_Process` using `Client_Process`

**Models.py**

```
class Process(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
    class Meta:
        db_table : 'process'

class Client(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client'

class Client_Process(models.Model):
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_process'


class Emp_Process(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Emp_Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table : 'emp_process'
```

Comment: `emp_process_obj.process.client_id` and ``emp_process_obj.process.process_id``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have you object, then why not just use?

```
process_id = object.process.id
client_id = object.process.client.id
```